# Custom Admin Color Scheme (WordPress)

Tags: php, wordpress

I am looking to create a plugin to add a custom theme to the user settings panel. I am looking to do two things.

1. How would I go about loading the CSS file from the plugin directory?
2. How do I add a script to remove the other schemes and set my scheme as default? (If possible)

I have the following so far. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
<?php

/*
@package HostingMate Admin Theme
*/


/*
Plugin Name: HM Admin Theme
Plugin URI: http://www.hosting-mate.com.au/plugin/admin-theme
Description: Admin Theme for WordPress - by Hosting Mate.
Author: Hosting Mate
Version: 0.1.1 BETA
Author URI: http://www.hostingmate.com.au/
License: 
*/


/*
===================================================
========== CREATE NEW ADMIN COLOR SCHEME ==========
===================================================
*/
function hostingmate_admin_color_schemes() {

  wp_admin_css_color(
    'hostingmate',
    'Hosting Mate',
    '',
    array( '#aa9d88', '#9ebaa0', '#738e96', '#f2fcff' )
  );
}

add_action('admin_init', 'hostingmate_admin_color_schemes');


?>
```

I have searched multiple websites in regards to both problem 1 and 2, however I havent found a solution for 2 and everyone seems to use their theme for their CSS admin color scheme file for problem 1.

Comment: my guess would be to use https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_print_styles/ hook - it fires after the styling of the admin pages has happened. else use admin_enqueue_script to load your css into admin head. As long as your plugin is activated and loaded, there should be no problem placing it in there

Answer (score 1):

Try this to get the css ,Hope this will help you

## I have 'colors-rtl.css' In folder 'yourfolder' name

```
function hostingmate_admin_color_schemes() {
$suffix = is_rtl() ? '-rtl' : '';
  wp_admin_css_color(
  'hostingmate', __( 'Hosting Mate', 'admin_schemes' ), 
    plugins_url( "yourfolder/colors$suffix.css", __FILE__ ),
    array( '#aa9d88', '#9ebaa0', '#738e96', '#f2fcff' ),
    array( 'base' => '#3299bb', 'focus' => '#452b72', 'current' => '#f5f5f5' )
  );
}

add_action('admin_init', 'hostingmate_admin_color_schemes');
```